# Set all values of IDictionary

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best way to "reset" a `Dictionary<int, bool>` type of structure (set all values to `true` or `false`). Currently I'm using a `ToDictionary()` extension method. Is there a way to do this by reusing the current instance?

This code throws an exception:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Sample
{
    [Test]
    public void SampleTest()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, bool>{{1, false}, {2, true}, {3, false}};
        foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
        {
            dictionary[key] = true;
        }

        Assert.That(dictionary[3], Is.True);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify or add a couple lines of code?  From the sounds of it, I think you want to set each item in the dictionary to a specific value, and unless there's a built in method it sounds like a foreach loop to me...

Comment: Loop over all keys in the dictionary and set their values to `true` or `false`? I doubt there's a more efficient way – and it's probably hardly less readable than a convoluted LINQ statement trying the same.

Comment: @Kendrick, yes I want to set all values to ture, foreach loop throws a collection modified exception

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foreach (int key in dictionary.Keys.ToList())
    dictionary[key] = true;
```

Comment: I haven't done any tests, but I think this is unnecessarily creating a List to loop over, while looping over the KeyValuePair's would be faster: `foreach (var kvp in dictionary) dictionary[kvp.Key] = true;`

Comment: @manixrock, your suggestion throws the same exception, as it attempts to modify the collection being looped over. The point of the call to `ToList` is to create and loop over a different collection entirely.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, you might wish to consider using the BitArray class (System.Collections.BitArray).  It has a SetAll method that will set all bits to either true or false:

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray(8);  //BitArray with 8 bits

ba[3] = true;  //set some bits
ba[6] = true;

ba.SetAll(false);  //Clear all
```

If you don't need a dictionary, you might consider this class.

Comment: +1 for BitArray, but in this case it has to be a dictionary (nonsequential ids).